# Sql Server Mangement Studio 2008 R2 only returns 3 records from every table and database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Alright this is killing me and I cannot figure out what is going on.

Starting today it seems if I open SSMS, right click on a table and select "New Query" then run a select start on any table it only returns 3, and only 3 records.

However if I right click on the table and run "Select top 1000 rows" it does successfully return the records.

The only difference I can see between the two is in option 2 where I "Select top 1000 rows" it runs from "localhost.master" However in the first option it runs from "localhost.DBName"

Has anyone ever seen this kind of behavior before? Is there anyway I can "reset" SSMS. I tried doing a clean repair which was successful however it has not fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in the SSMS that will allow to specify the number of rows for display/edit using right click on table, It is in Tools --> Options --> "SQL Server Object Explorer" --> Commands. These might have changed, please update them and try.

Also, for more details please refer to the link [Useful Settings in SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s218/useful_sql_server_developer_settings.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try typing:

```
set rowcount 0
```

into SSMS and running it to reset the limit; you may have previously done a

```
set rowcount 3
```

and forgot to undo it.

Comment: this seems to get it, however if I close out of SSMS and reopen (just a local instance) the behavior comes back... so strange?